# How can i get array values from current field in document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

help me please : 
a have such order collection with this schema :

```
const OrderSchema =  new Schema(
{
    doctorId:       { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'},
    patientId:      { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'},
    orderTime:      { type : String , default:''},
    createdAt:      { type : Date, default:Date.now },
    approvedByDoctor:{ type :Boolean, default:false },
    price:{type:Number,default:0}
},
```

);

and a have 10 documents like this, what query must i do to get array of "orderTime" from each document? thanks

Comment: can you provide an example of the results you want to create? ta

Comment: [{createdTime:".....time"},{createdTime:".....time"},{createdTime:"......time"}]

Comment: or [createdTime, createdTime...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregation framework to create the array. Essentially you'd want to group all the documents, use the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator operator to create the list. Follow this example to get the gist:

```
Order.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "orderTimes": { "$push": "$orderTime" }         
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result[0].orderTimes);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's what i want !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have documents which look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("578f73d17612ac41eb736641"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-20T12:51:29.558Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("578f73e57612ac41eb736642"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-20T12:51:49.701Z")
}
```

then you can generate a result document containing an array of createdAt dates which looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : null, "creationDates" : [ ISODate("2016-07-20T12:51:29.558Z"), ISODate("2016-07-20T12:51:49.701Z") ] }
```

by running the following aggregate query:

```
db.<your_collection>.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":null,"creationDates":{$push:"$createdAt"}}}])
```

this will basically group all documents in the collection (`"_id":null`) and push the the values from the createdAt fields into an array (`"creationDates":{$push:"$createdAt"}`)